# Passing structs to functions across packages

Tags: pointers, go, struct

In an attempt to become more familiar with go, I am trying to refactor some code which is already working fine.

The original code has three structs:

```
type ConfigGroup struct {
        Interval int
        Tprefix string
        Target []string
}

type ConfigDefaults struct {
        Interval int
        Sprefix string
}

type Config struct {
    Group map[string]*ConfigGroup
    Defaults ConfigDefaults
}
```

These structs get passed to a function like so:

```
func runpinger(clientStatsd statsd.Statter, defaults *ConfigDefaults, group *ConfigGroup) {
// some stuff here
}
```

Now, I've reworked the config (which uses gocfg) to use [hcl](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl) instead, which seems to provide a cleaner config syntax.

I've moved the config parser into a package, `config`, with structs that look like this:

```
type Config struct {
  Interval int            `hcl:"interval"`
  Prefix   string         `hcl:"prefix"`
  Groups   []TargetGroups `hcl:"target_group"`
}

type TargetGroups struct {
  Name     string    `hcl:",key"`
  Prefix   string    `hcl:"prefix"`
  Interval int       `hcl:"interval"`
  Targets  []Targets `hcl:"target"`
}

type Targets struct {
  Address string `hcl:"address"`
  Label   string `hcl:"label"`
}
```

and then a function in `config` package that looks like this:

```
func Parse(ConfigFile string) (*Config, error) {

  result := &Config{}
  var errors *multierror.Error

  config, err := ioutil.ReadFile(ConfigFile)

  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  hclParseTree, err := hcl.Parse(string(config))
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  if err := hcl.DecodeObject(&result, hclParseTree); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  return result, errors.ErrorOrNil()

}
```

Now, in my main package I'd like to pass these structs to the function again. How can I do this across packages?

I tried:

```
func(runpinger config *config.Config) {
 // here
}
```

But that didn't seem to work. Ideally, I'd like to just pass a pointer to the "sub-struct" (ie the TargetGroups struct) as well, although I'm not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass the structs to the main package, just check that you put `import "path/to/config"` at the top of your file.

The path has to be the full path to your package from your `$GOPATH/src/` directory

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did. Not sure why I was finding this so darn difficult, but it's working now